# Is it possible to run angular project 8.x when the CLI installed is 10.x

Tags: angular-cli

I'm working on a project witch use angular 8, and I've update the angular CLI to the last version (10), then I can't run the project via (`ng serve`), several errors shown, is those errors relative to the angular version or some thing else, I'm new at angular, please help me.

Comment: *several errors shown*. What errors?

Comment: Actually, it should works. I would be also interested in the error messages. Are you sure you use Node 10.13 or later? Sometimes it helped me to update the project with the following command: `ng update`. There is also an [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/) with more details.